# Piping variables into a powershell array

Tags: arrays, powershell, variables

I'm working to automate counts from some raw data files. I have everything down to setting the variables from the results of my loop. Now I need to index those results into a multi-dimensional array in a specific order in order to pass it as an argument to my Excel macro.

I haven't worked much with arrays, hash tables or multi-dimensional arrays so I'm completely lost here.

```bsh
function Count-FsbAlt 
{
    foreach ($Campaign in $Campaigns) #Gets total count of downloaded file
    {
            $file = import-csv "\\SEAGATE-FGS\clients\Federal Savings Bank\File Transfer Folder\${mmddyy} FSB\Original\Altair_originals\${yyyyMMdd}_FSB_${Campaign}_Final.csv"
            New-Variable -name ${campaign}_Total -Value $file.count -force
            Get-variable -name ${campaign}_Total
```

Name                           Value
----                           -----
FHA_All States_Total           99
FHA_West_Total                 53
FHAPR                          11
FHASPO                         141
Total_FHA                      152
VA LOANS_All States_Total      942
VA LOANS_West_Total            263
VA PROSPECT_All States_Total   1129
VA PROSPECT_West_Total         422

I need these results piped into the array. As a table, it would need to look something like this:

1. FSB    Columbus     D-1-VAPROS     1129
2. FSB    Columbus     D-1-FHAPR      11
3. FSB    Chicago      D-1-FHAPO      141

Comment: the `Name Value` collection doesn't seem to have a meaningful connection to your "desired table". [*frown*] ///// please post - [1] the 1st few lines of each input data set [2] how you want those to look in the output [3] any selection criteria you consider to be needed to get from [1] to [2].

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create an empty array before your foreach loop to add the values you want to output from each $Campaign in $Campaigns like this:

`$CampaignsOutput = @()`

Inside the foreach loop you'll need to create a PSObject and add a NoteProperty to that object for each "column" that you want in the output like this:

```
            $CampaignRow = New-Object -TypeName psobject
            $CampaignRow | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Column1 -Value $Value1
            $CampaignRow | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Column2 -Value $Value2
```

Then add that to the array like this:

`$CampaignsOutput += $CampaignRow`

So your final script will look something like this:

```
function Count-FsbAlt 
{
    $CampaignsOutput = @()

    foreach ($Campaign in $Campaigns) #Gets total count of downloaded file
    {
            $file = import-csv "\\SEAGATE-FGS\clients\Federal Savings Bank\File Transfer Folder\${mmddyy} FSB\Original\Altair_originals\${yyyyMMdd}_FSB_${Campaign}_Final.csv"
            $CampaignRow = New-Object -TypeName psobject
            $CampaignRow | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Column1 -Value $Value1
            $CampaignRow | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Column2 -Value $Value2
            $CampaignsOutput += $CampaignRow
    }

    # Do something with $CampaignsOutput
}
```

Comment: I see this a lot, but it is not a good idea to build the object array using the `+=` assignment operator, like `$CampaignsOutput += $CampaignRow` as you rebuild the array with every iteration. It is better to just drop each object in the pipeline: `Write-Output $CampaignRow` and eventually assign the pipeline to the variable: '$CampaignRow = foreach ($Campaign in $Campaigns) {...'